# Flutter 4k60fps Video Performance on AndroidTV

Tags: android, flutter, vlc, frame-rate

I've tried throwing every idea at this problem but I'm not sure if it's just Flutter being slow or something.

Details:

I'm using my **Sonk 4k AndroidTV** as my physical device and have been loading the apps onto it for testing.

I've got a **4k60fps** video that I'm playing from a LAN RaspberryPi (served by nginx).

To get a solid baseline I've played this video on my Macbook using VLC from the Pi and it runs great.  I've also loaded the VLC app onto my Sony AndroidTV and it plays great using that as well (again from the LAN RaspberryPi).

I've been working on a Flutter app to view 4k60fps videos.  With this same video file being served from the Pi I've tried several video options in Flutter.

- video_player
- chewie
- better_player
- vlc_player_flutter

All are able to play it but with more jank/stutter then when I play it through the AndroidTV VLC app (it's quite annoying to watch).

I've tried doing a `flutter run --release` to make sure there isn't any overhead from the debug build.  I've also attempted to do a `profile` build and look at the performance stats (it showed jank, but I wouldn't say an insane amount).

Are there any other great ideas that I'm missing or possibly something I'm doing wrong in Flutter?  Here's the VLC widget I've created, the better_player, chewie, and video_player widgets are all pretty much the same as this one.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/flutter_vlc_player.dart';
import 'package:photo_tv_app/models/media_objects.models.dart';

class VLCViewer extends StatefulWidget {
  VLCViewer({required this.newKey, required this.viewerObject})
      : super(key: newKey);

  final MediaViewerObject viewerObject;
  final UniqueKey newKey;

  @override
  VLCViewerState createState() => VLCViewerState();
}

class VLCViewerState extends State<VLCViewer> {
  late VlcPlayerController _videoPlayerController;

  Future<void> initializePlayer() async {}

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('VLC Viewer Init');
    super.initState();

    _videoPlayerController = VlcPlayerController.network(
                widget.viewerObject.objectPath,
                hwAcc: HwAcc.auto,
                autoPlay: true,
                options: VlcPlayerOptions(),
              );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() async {
    super.dispose();
    await _videoPlayerController.stopRendererScanning();
    await _videoPlayerController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: VlcPlayer(
        controller: _videoPlayerController,
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        placeholder: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'd really like to be able to solve this issue in Flutter but I've seemingly run out of ideas and things to Google.

**Edit 1:**
I also tried it on   native_video_view plugin

For what it's worth I also include the same video as a bundled asset and get the same result as network play.

Comment: 1) Check github issues (open & closed) to see if anyone found similar problems/workarounds. 2) And changing the buffer/cache size of the Flutter plugin doesn't help? 3) As you are streaming 4k60fps you should state the codec/bitrate/profile that is being sent by the server (more for future reference).

Comment: Good ideas.
1) I had searched through several but couldn't find anything substantial or related
2) None of the plugins I've attempted seem to have caching options (for what it's worth I've also tried bundling the video as an asset in the APK with the same results)
3) Details of the video:  mp4 ~470mb  codecs: AAC, HEVC (Parameter Sets in Bitstream)

Comment: some logs would be helpful.

Comment: if the flutter vlc plugin lacks hardware acceleration, then you are out of luck

Comment: What logs can I provide that would be helpful?

VLC does have an option to force hardware acceleration on, which I did without a change in the result

Comment: https://jhomlala.github.io/betterplayer/#/bufferingconfiguration?id=buffering-configuration,https://jhomlala.github.io/betterplayer/#/cacheconfiguration?id=cache-configuration

Comment: I had tried BetterPlayer and it had the issue both with the video playing locally (bundled in the app) and on network.  So I'm not sure if extending the buffers would help for this.

Comment: @Fernker did you ever solve this? I'm facing the same issue here, and struggling to find where the performance issue is in my setup.

Comment: @dKen I sadly did not solve it with Flutter.  I did a simple native Android app with the same network videos and it plays fine without dropping frames.  So it seems Flutter still needs some improvement in this area.

Comment: Okay, thanks @Fernker, it's a shame that Flutter isn't up to the task. I'm just building a play-thing in my spare time so I can't justify rebuilding in native. Thanks again for getting back to me.

Comment: No problem @dKen I really wish I had found a good Flutter solution for it.  You can possibly look into bundling your Flutter into a native app where the video is handled by the native app and then you show your Flutter app view for everything else.  I couldn't find tons of great information on it but it is possible supposedly.